# Glass fish HTTPS redirect to a different URL

Tags: ssl, https, glassfish-3

im using glassfish 3.1.2.2 i have been map my domain name to "www.testdomain.com" in my host file. my unsecured files are open like below url.

```
"http://www.testdomain.com:8083/index.html"
```

but the problem is when im trying to open a secure page it redirect to a different url
like below. it adds some prefix that is actually my application name in front of the URL.

```
https://www.testdomain.com:8181/myapplicationname/securepage.xhtml
```

i want my secure page to open like below mentioned URL

```
https://www.testdomain.com:8181/securepage.xhtml
```

do i have to change any glassfish setting for this? or how should i do it?

Answer (score 0):

after 4 hours playing with the glassfish i have finally found a solution
it happens becouse i was setup my default apllication in glassfish. what i did was

```
GlassFish -> default-config -> Virtual Servers -> Server
```

and there u have "Default Web Module:" make it to "empty"

and also

```
GlassFish -> server-config -> Virtual Servers -> Server
```

and there also u have set the "Default Web Module:" to "empty"

and then

Goto

```
Application -> select your deployed web application
```

and make "Context Root:" and make it to only "/" 
that resolved my problem